# HTML button to load data and refresh UI

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

Here the situation:

In my html page I have a link, which `onclick` runs a PHP script.

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="target"></iframe>

<a href="path/to/my/script.php" target="target">Load new tasks</a>
```

I use an invisible iframe to execute the script but I stay on the same page.

This link executes `script.php` which updates mysql database, but in order to see new content the page must be reloaded.

Of course I can always create a separate button/link that reloads current page.

But I wonder if there is a way to execute the PHP script and reload current page with one html button.

Comment: There sure is and it's called Ajax.

Comment: USE Ajax+Jquery to reach your goal..

Comment: You should use ajax for this

Comment: I think the OP gets it ;)

Comment: You don't realy need AJAX in this case. If you do want the page to reload anyway, why do you need a hidden iframe to execute? You could POST the entire page which would run your PHP script and reload the page in one shot

Comment: After re-reading this and some of the comments, as said; you don't need Ajax or even JS for that matter; it can be done in pure PHP. When you UPDATE your DB, and upon success, don't echo anything, just do a header redirect to the same page; that's what I do in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Better use it this way:

1: Use a common Javascript Framework, for example JQuery

2: Create your Link and a Div for your Content:

```
<a href="#" id="reload">Update my Data and reload my new Content</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

3: Use Jquery to add the click event to your link:

```
$('#reload').click(function(e) {
    // Prevent from going to the link provided in href
    e.preventDefault();

    // make POST Request to script

    $.post( "myScriptHandler.php", { value1: "1", value2: "2" })
    .done(function( data ) {

        // if done, refresh my Div with html content from your PHP Script
        $('#result').html('')
        $('#result').load('mydata.php');


    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAx - just return a script into the iframe which updates the toplevel page...

```
<?php

....
$new=run_updates();
print "<div id='newcontent'>$new</div>\n";
?>
<script>
var dest=parent.document.getElementById('oldcontent');
var src=document.getElementById('newcontent');
dest.innerHTML=src.innerHTML;
</script>
```

(not tested, YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

I show you how to use Ajax in this case:

here is your html and js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".link").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "your_php_script.php",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        location.reload(true);    
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<html>
  <body>
    <a class="link" target="target">Load new tasks</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you click the 'a' tag, the jQuery Ajax script call your php script, and when it return with success, then your page will be refresh.